# Is react/angular application which communicates to API to fetch data can be considered as a static web app

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I want to use **Azure Static Web Apps** for Angular/React applications.
I am a bit confused since my application will communicate with an API to fetch data that will be required to render the page. That means the pages are not static rather dynamic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview

According to this, https://www.staticapps.org/articles/defining-static-web-apps/ the JavaScript Apps which communicate with API also can be considered as Static App. Can I consider this is true for Azure Static Web App as well?

Comment: The files you're actually serving are static, that doesn't mean they can't show different things given different responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static Application can have APIs, Static here refers to the pages that end users would see. Static websites contain fixed number of pages and format of web page is fixed which delivers information to the client, that does not mean you can't fetch data which is displayed from the backend through APIs

In terms of Azure Static Web apps, it has built in way to build your APIs with Azure Functions.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen that the Azure Static Web apps have a built-in way for APIs. But we can also use other regular APIs or from different servers without any issue. Am I right?

Comment: You can use it, but you would nee another way to hose those APIs

Comment: In my case, the APIs are hosted as separate web services. Do I need to do any modifications to my Angular App? I could not found any resources about that.

Comment: You don't have to do any modification, just make sure you have proxy configured